# Google cloud boot disk space not matching

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, diskspace

I want to check which directories are consuming most of my Google cloud's boot disk space. The disk's capacity is 10 GB, which is 100% full, but when I go and check the space usage, / sums to be just about 2.6 GBs.

I used the command df -h, which shows

[image]

So as per the output above, the root / is consuming 9.8 GBs, but when I do du -sh on root / , the space consumed just comes around 2.6 GBs.

[image]

I am wondering where the rest of space is getting consumed?

Comment: What does `sudo du -shx /` produce?

Comment: Maybe try running ncdu (https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).  You can install this on debian using `sudo apt-get install ncdu`.

Comment: @Kolban it's same , just that I don't get error message related to not process directory access errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue, it was because many processes were still referring deleted files, and hence df would report a different number than du. Instance restart solved it.